# Access blocked: Authorization Error (The OAuth client was not found)

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-oauth

```
const express=require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const axios=require('axios');
const app=express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

dotenv.config({path: '/config.env'});

// Declaring the * credential * for google oauth 
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const URI= `http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback`;
// console.log(process.env.RETURN_URI);
console.log(URI);

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send(`Welcome Go to for Login: /auth/google `);
  res.end();
})
app.get('/auth/google',(req,res)=>{
  // res.send("hello from the server");
  console.log("hello i am rahul");
  const AUTH_URL =`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${URI}&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`;
  console.log("hello auth_url next");

  
  res.redirect(AUTH_URL);
  // res.end();
});
app.get('/auth/google/callback',async (req,res)=>{
  const {code}=req.query;
  // if code is not exist - authenication failed!!
  if(!code){
    res.status(400).send("Authenication failed!!!");
  }
  try{

    const AxiosUrlToken = process.env.AXIOS_URL_TOKEN;

    const AxiosUrlMe = process.env.AXIOS_URL_ME;

    const option ={
      code,
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      redirect_uri: URI,
      grant_type:'authorization_code'
    }

    const tokenResponse = await axios.post(AxiosUrlToken,option);

    const accessToken = tokenResponse.data.acess_token;

    const userResponse = await axios.get(AxiosUrlMe,{
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`},
    });
    const userData = userResponse.data;
    res.json(userData);

  }catch(err){
    res.status(500).send('Failed to fetch user Data');

  }

})

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
  console.log("Running on port "+PORT);
})
```

```
PORT = 3000
CLIENT_ID = 363304762195-akqg0ddq19dodtklmhe31ff52pd045t5.apps.googleusercontent.com
CLIENT_SECRET = *******
RETURN_URI = http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback
AXIOS_URL_TOKEN = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
AXIOS_URL_ME = https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

## Access blocked: Authorization Error

process.env.RETURN_URI giving me undefined , please help to figure out my mistake

and when I go the url(http://localhost:3000/google/auth) -

***. It shows this ***

The OAuth client was not found.
If you are a developer of this app, see **[error details](https://accounts.google.com/)**.

> Error 401: invalid_client

How can I fix it?

Comment: i would reset your client secret you just shared it with everyone.